# How to launch a react-redux-toastr action message from another action

Tags: alert, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using react-redux-toastr to generate alerts in my app. These alerts are to be shown to the user for a period of time. I want to launch these messages after another actions is successfully done or failed programmatically. I am using the [Readme](https://www.libhive.com/providers/npm/packages/react-redux-toastr#lhCodeExamples) bundled with the package.

I did the first 4 steps as indicated in the read me. To launch the message action from another action (custom) I did the following:

```
//in the '../actions/action.js' folder
import { actions } from 'react-redux-toastr'

export function showMessage(title, message, options){
  return dispatch => dispatch(actions.add({
    type: options.status,
    title,
    message,
    options
 }))
}

export const toastrInfoOption = {
  icon: 'info',
  status: 'info'
}

//I am using the thunk middleware
export function test(){
  return dispatch => dispatch(showMessage('Hello','World', toastrInfoOption))
}
```

When the test action is triggered I am expecting to see the information alert with "Hello" as title and "World" as the message, but that is not the case. I don't know what I am doing wrong, or any other way to achieve my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your action creator is not right. Try this:

```
 export function test() {
    return dispatch => showMessage('Hello','World', toastInfoOption)  (dispatch)
 }
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. Sometimes, javascript is just so creepy! I have done something like: `dispatch => dispatch(showMessage('Hello','World', toastrInfoOption))` before and it worked. Please what's the difference?

Comment: showMessage return a function that need a parameter which is dispatch;  it's no meaning dispatch(shouwMessage(params));  Another way is to modify showMessage, not return dispatch function but return the action object, so that you can dispatch it outside

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.